# searching trough object keys including numbers with for

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, key-value

I have a object that looks like this:

```
obj: {
centricAccountId1: number;
centricAccountId2: number;
...
centricAccountId10: number;
}
```

I'm writing a for loop to assign values to each key:

```
for (let i=1; i < 11 ;i++) {
    obj.centricAccountId${i} = //something
}
```

`documentItem.centricAccountId${i}` doesn't seem to work. how should I iterate through these keys without repeating their names ?

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but the code was wrong. You'll need to access the keys using square brackets and use template literals. You can try something like this

```js
const obj =  {
centricAccountId1: 123,
centricAccountId2: 234,
centricAccountId3: 891
}

for (let i=1; i <= 3 ;i++) {
    obj[`centricAccountId${i}`] = obj[`centricAccountId${i}`]+1
}

console.log(obj)
```